# Detect when the local video ended and move to another Scene

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, avplayer, skscene

How to detect that the local video ended and move to another Scene?

this is the code :

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class intro: SKScene {

  override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
      let urlStr = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Opening", ofType: "mp4")
      let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: urlStr!)

      let player = AVPlayer(url: url as URL)

      let videoNode = SKVideoNode(avPlayer: player)
      videoNode.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
      videoNode.size = CGSize(width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.height)
      videoNode.zPosition = 1

      addChild(videoNode)
      videoNode.play()
  }

  override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
      // Called before each frame is rendered
  }
}
```

i need to know how to move to another scene once the video ends . 
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fire notification like this:

```
  NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.playerDidFinishPlaying),
                                               name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,
                                               object: self.player!.currentItem)



 @objc func playerDidFinishPlaying(){
    print("Player finished")
}
```

Comment: Hey Sir , thank you for the comment . i did try this but i got this Error Value of type 'intro' has no member 'player'. at  object: self.player.currentItem .

Comment: intro should be the name of the class . your answer helped me . i had to write "player.currentItem"